# Resolve multiple callback and promises in a tuple with the right type

Tags: typescript

Here is a playground with the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=134#code/PQKgUAKgFgpgBAMwJYCcDOAXOAbGBzOAewTgFsBPOABxUICNdS4k04pCB3ODQuPGLChhpC2AG7xSAV2wYkVXHADGAQ2zY6KpQGtWSAHY8i++Ain6lcwvrgr9AEz4DusOELQyMrFd+WEUQpbYlBjkVDCOGFIKMGAgwGBgBhgwKAha8ABSAIpSqeQAIjAIqUL2ADwQAHxwAN5gcI1wYmp5AFxwEGAAvnDAwHAAVlKYiP4u8DAAHiqkMdy8QqSEEhNwpf6JZhZWNu6iEuUAwmoaWrrrUykO3vrkANoAulUAFAB0H9uWSNZoHSfqTQ6NAASjqDSauEEwk8rAAvHAngBuCGNBD+F5KX5YEjERDmb6-MH1Jqktww2RoN5UEZQF4IF4gkEo0ndVHkqIoPYUrwotlgLH6UYIACMcARjPFNRFKMFwoATOK4JK4TUAESYFBqlFgKFuJX7cQwekigA0iHlzL6AxQzFYeNC4Vsdye5oAkgByRzYJDaeBILBGOjwB1heD3fRSUjBlDmzUGPCPAW-UQwN7YQh4F4oZmJUCQVxoGCCxxUFQoLAsOAcANQai0UgsYRvOAAMXGGFcgX8jjdcBG8DsRGwjgk6B+NjxOTyKEo6NtuDwWkoQh8vzgIjYnDgfYHcGn+SKJQCETIKkowaIUgw9hUKXsbziCTAX125JERoAsnZyJVzQAlV5yzwP591yQ9ilKCJKiqJ4QQ6f8njqa04H0QgsFOTpnUcf9bCENY0FmeA6GvHc4HsawPSwbQ0K4dguCMaYaGEVhOzvdk9XcWEOh-JCEWRdl+jYVJ4A4eAsTma94E7eAuMpd0cEgwMoDvK8sAdVxplmGJ2SETluQ8Sk+USPV7GKABlDAUATABCDoD1nI8oIqeN9DwKokRQzsqzM49TxrdQOSkLlbA3KyE3NKEPVYQjKDVXy1V1ZxfIAOSjGM7LAmdCkgk8KkjaNUg8ryoB83L-KQQK9OCmwVFQ9LUkigRoo3c84AAFnlEznACA1hAOGBvzuF57l8yzrLc81UoalBHitISAuwIKQvueLijVc1OqTISAAkRLIvB0LgRUaHoRg0HNCBzKOPw5mwFQDG8OhCFI6bCttYMEyIEhHSycDHNyspygKmMqgU8wzPQDA7EcDgoAvUiAxazBKqWhhCB0L75zINMwCEgBBBw3FtKtQydcwaM4fRXTIjgXpHHBfVk20g2ksNvFYe5XLwc0QdSJMksEXqEUNCQhvIEaxvCybyOKNL3qmuWZrmzyhO8mL2BkRw1E3OmUG0bDidtNBNYZy8yfDbneZm633seIA).

The first leg of my problem is how to get resolve multiple callbacks into one function and get the results as a correctly typed tuple

```
interface JQueryDeferred<T> {
    value: T
} // just for the example to remove the error

function resolve<Callbacks extends any[]>(...functions: Callbacks) {
    let results = [];
    for(const f of functions) {
        results.push(f());
    }
    return results;
}

const f1 = () => 1;
const f2 = () => "str";

let r = resolve(f1, f2); // r is of type any[], I'd like it to be of type [number, string]
console.log(r);
```

Also, how would you do it if resolve were taking an array directly instead of varargs?

The second part is with promises. For the record I use an old version of JQuery for legacy reasons so how I use JQueryDeferred may be outdated.

```
function resolveMany<T, R>(args: JQueryDeferred<T>[]): R[] { // not all T and R are the same but I don't know how to express that
    let results: any[] = [];
    // here we compute the results, I lefet that out of the example
    return results;
}

let defString!: JQueryDeferred<string>; // this defered will return a string, let's say "def"
let defNumber!: JQueryDeferred<number>; // this defered will return a number, let's say 42

let rr = resolveMany([defString, defNumber]); // will return ["def", 42]
// Here I got 2 problems, TSC complains about defNumber being of type JQueryDeferred<number>, I understand why but it's still blocking for me.
// And rr is of type unknown[], I would like rr to be types as [string, number]

let rrr = resolveMany([defString, defNumber, defNumber]); // this should also work and rrr should be of type [string, number, number]
```

Is there any way to do all that in typescript?

Comment: What about `function resolveMany<R>(args: JQueryDeferred<number | string>[]): R[]`?

Comment: @MoshFeu That would be valid typing but that wouldn't be enought since I wouldn't know statically the length of the array (it would be an array and I want a tuple). Also I woudn't know if the first element is a number or a string. Also, it wouldn't work with custom types instead of number or string.

Comment: Using this type you don't have to know the length of the array. If you want tuple, `resolveMany([defString, defNumber, defNumber])` is not valid. But if you still want this, you can use `[JQueryDeferred<string>, JQueryDeferred<number>]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all of these, the compiler does not automatically infer the correlation in tuple types between the input and output.  It's kind of beyond the abilities of the compiler to do so; you could probably get something automatically to handle *length*, at least if you changed the loop-with-`push` into an array `map()` method (see [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841)), but understanding that each element will turn `JQueryDeferred<X>` into `X` for different `X` is not going to happen without something like *higher kinded types* of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  And that doesn't look like it will be implemented anytime soon.

So let's give up on having the compiler infer such types automatically, and focus on *telling* the compiler what types to expect.  This will involve type manipulation like [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), [tuple mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) and [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to describe the types.  And it will also involve [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to tell the compiler that the implementation indeed conforms to the types we describe, since it won't be able to verify that itself.

---

Here's how one could write your `resolve()`, which I'll call `resolveCallbacks()` to distinguish it from some of the later operations:

```
function resolveCallbacks<T extends readonly any[]>(
  ...functions: { [I in keyof T]: () => T[I] }): T {
  let results = [] as unknown as { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
  for (const f of functions) {
    results.push(f());
  }
  return results;
}
```

This function is generic in `T`, the expected output tuple/array type.  The `functions` parameter is a mapped version of `T` where each element of `T` is replaced with a function that produces that element.  Inside the implementation, we assert that the type of `results` is (a non-readonly version of) the output type `T`.

And we can see that it works:

```
const f1 = () => 1;
const f2 = () => "str";

let r = resolveCallbacks(f1, f2);
// let r: [number, string]
console.log(r); // [1, "str"]
```

---

Changing from varargs to an array is as easy as removing the `...` rest parameter modifier:

```
function resolveCallbackArray<T extends readonly any[]>(
  functions: { [I in keyof T]: () => T[I] }): T {
  let results = [] as unknown as { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
  for (const f of functions) {
    results.push(f());
  }
  return results;
}
```

There's a little snag with type inference; the compiler will see `[f1, f2]` and tend to infer it as type `Array<(()=>string) | (()=>number)>` and not as a tuple.  (Usually people want arrays and not tuples, so that's the default inference.)  If you want the compiler to keep track of the order, you need to tell it.  One way to do so is via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
let rArr = resolveCallbackArray([f1, f2] as const); // const assertion
// let rArr: readonly [number, string]
console.log(rArr); // [1, "str"]
```

So that works too.

---

For the rest of it, I'm not 100% sure what you're doing with `JQueryDeferred` because you supplied your own example typing that has nothing to do with asynchronous behavior.  Assuming that `JQueryDeferred` just has a `value` property, then we can turn `resolveCallbacks` into `resolveDeferreds` in a straightforward way:

```
function resolveDeferreds<T extends readonly any[]>(
  ...deferreds: { [I in keyof T]: JQueryDeferred<T[I]> }): T {
  let results = [] as unknown as { -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
  for (const d of deferreds) {
    results.push(d.value)
  }
  return results;
}

let defString: JQueryDeferred<string> = { value: "abc" }
let defNumber: JQueryDeferred<number> = { value: 123 }    
let rD = resolveDeferreds(defString, defNumber);
//let rD: [string, number]
console.log(rD); // ["abc", 123]
```

---

Finally, the typing for the version with `Promise`s, or something like it, requires that the output also be wrapped in a `Promise`, but otherwise it's the same:

```
function resolvePromises<T extends readonly any[]>(
  ...promises: { [I in keyof T]: Promise<T[I]> }): Promise<T> {
  return Promise.all(promises) as any;
}
```

As for the implementation, I just used the existing [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function here since I don't intend to reinvent the wheel.  You could do it if you had to.  And we still need that type assertion because `Promise.all()` doesn't strongly type arbitrary tuples (as of now anyway, see [microsoft/TypeScript#39788](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39788)).  And we can see that it works:

```
let promString = new Promise<string>((r) => r("hello"));
let promNumber = new Promise<number>((r) => r(456));

const rP = resolvePromises(promString, promNumber);
// const rP: Promise<[string, number]>
rP.then(sn => console.log(sn)); // ["hello, 456"]
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYGc4BsBuqDCAhllgEaEQDW6APACqKoAeUqYAJuiqoewlgE9EhMAIDaAXQB8ACgB0C0JFgJ0ALkQBvRGICSiGEkqoBcYIjoSNMgJSIAvFIt6JiAL42NDTQChEiLFQobnQQLCguex1XQi5wSjA4AHckWK1EAFo0Xn4hMQBpAyMTMwsrZ3zXNwBuP0RgOGREGQhVYPNSpWh4MHQ7X39-NFDw9DkABxB0AAsZYFsbWv83OrQoEGQkYbCI2pWfVt72gEYHZrtHRGPaw-R2gCYz2wcnACI75Ffan0Dgpqjhtg8EQSOQqOg5scADT1e6LHwAegRASCKA0YjAIAAtqRUMgYR9DABzCQHVTYVByLBwIkyZCLRBInTQxDvKCfUk+HxdFRbDBAgjEMgUSgAQWQyEIAnojBYbE43ByYEEwlEklkPJ66nSeiKiGMpnMlmsFycdBc7k8Fi0dV+IR2kWiwjiYASyVSXG0WR4fGVeUKhn1JSN5XNlXcS3qjWat3aiE64G6qn6dSGGAdEyms3mNnhy1WQQ2fJGux8+x+qOQ4v+IQFIOFVGrUpkYmALOA9xiXFj8KZdqrEo02V9Kox2Nx+MQhLAJLJvQpVJpdOrDKZYhZbI5XMMrGQwAoqEQACkAIogPECAAiqGAeLQ7HoTgGiBwxHPXjLXM1CFruFQ19vCVUE4GVmFYDguGHXJVXEaR5AUdgbzvYDtW0XVAwNUpjWPM8LwA5CH3NXRpEtLwbX8ft01GM5JGdRB4kSFI6K9KC-R0ANikNMovAKKpIwaJoWjaRB2HjcxEMA+8+nIwZtlGTMZhkdg5FfLBzxsOoVjTdZNntUY9i5O0JIAZXZYkNFPc9kCvJCgIfaciScKJtFU99WUIUgIFedwK2CCSADlxzxCzcOs-C7JoTEcTxJz0lc1ANGOe4AGYfP7S8zkBP9wqkpSb1M5BiRhAKgvpWokXS9EHJhKKJ1JW4F2pWlkEvVdkTEV4PK8mEkuSzluUTXlfzwAAFZA4CxGB0AwUC5QgxURyEERYNkBQJnGybptQnR9Aw4NuMQMaJqm1B6BcJwPA0I7NtOugnwLHSkGuk65CFGRxg2k7pLSZaDN8xAPomgriTOMBUCSQ7PummgHNkOlTRQGRXmmVASDgV5c1qO1AaxQLoprMGIee6HapimR4ZeRGABYAFYADZMa5WMUBGzL+T-YmMHejbgZnGEcbxide2RZnkBGq6odOsRqsQUnkGkHwxbkKAUbAGR0CQS4GsCRdaQ1zHGXa5HUepGFabp15OSAA)